# Pyscripter on Cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, pyscripter

Question: How to install Pyscripter on Cygwin?

Scenerio: I have installed portable apps on a usb, then installed cygwin portable version 0.9 on it. Under cygwin, I have installed Python 2.6. I am curerntly using it with the idle IDE but I would like to use Pyscripter instead.

I can not use portable python because I need to install additional modules on python such as pyevolve and Cantera. Alternatively, maybe someone could let me know how to add these modules to portable python.

Answer (score 1):

You can create [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) in your usb. And just switch it on in any other computer via Cygwin from our usb. It is not a way to install Pyscripter. But it is way for add modules to your portable version of python.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else trying this, note that PyScripter is intended to run under Windows, not Linux. The steps are: (1) in Windows, install a python distribution [from python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/), and (2) in Windows, install [PyScripter](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyscripter/?source=typ_redirect).

Note, too, that PyScripter has the desired console (interactive python interpreter) window, and a pip-based package manager that allows adding packages. For example, to add Pandas to an app, do the following:

```
menu: Tools menu
submenu: Tools
menu item: Install packages with pip
Package Name: pandas
```

The correct pandas package with required dependencies will be installed. (At least, that is what happened in my case). I was then able to `import pandas` into my app and use it without any problem.

Cygwin is a Linux environment that installs/runs under Windows. One of its main claims to fame is that it allows you to use Linux commands at the Windows CMD prompt. It also allows you to install/run certain Linux apps, which you then run in the Cygwin (and/or Cygwin-X graphical) environment. For example, it is possible to install/run Eric6 (a graphical Linux python IDE) under Cygwin. (I tried that, it worked - but not as great as Pyscripter)

For my money, I found that Pyscripter under Windows works great - and is much, much nicer than Eric6 under Cygwin. I am a Notepad++ user for HTML/js/PHP and started out using Anaconda (Spyder) to code in Python. PyScripter is much closer to NPP than, for e.g., Spyder or IDLE or Eric6 - and is more like what I had hoped to find in the Python world - and it simply runs under Windows like any other Windows app.

References:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyscripter

https://github.com/pyscripter/pyscripter